# Nowhere dense in $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

$S=\{ A^k X \mid \ k \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\} \ \}$ where $A \in M_n (\mathbb{C}) $ and $X \in \mathbb{C}^n$.

Show that $S$ is nowhere dense in $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By a base change we may assume that $A$ has Jordan normal form.
If $\mathring{\overline S}$ is nonempty, then the same holds for the projection onto some substapce.
Hence it is sufficient to consider the restruction to a single Jordan block, i.e. assume $Ae_i=\lambda e_i+e_{i-1}$ for $1<i\le n$ and $Ae_1=\lambda e_1$.
Project again, this time to $\langle e_n\rangle$. Here we have just a sequence of the form $\lambda ^kx\in\mathbb C$. The closure of this is a subset of $S^1$ if $|\lambda|=1$, a discrete set if $|\lambda|>1$, a discrete set $\cup\{0\}$ if $|\lambda|<1$, or just $\{0\}$ if $\lambda=0$ or $x=0$; at any rate it has no interior.